# Define nested properties via TS

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

have a such object:

```
const countrySize = {
  "af":{
     "name":"Afghanistan",
     "shoeSizeLocale":"EU/IT"
  },
  "al":{
     "name":"Albania",
     "shoeSizeLocale":"AU"
  },
  "dz":{
     "name":"Algeria",
     "shoeSizeLocale":"EU/IT"
  },
  "ar":{
     "name":"Argentina",
     "shoeSizeLocale":"US/CA"
  },
  ...
}
```

how can i get type of shoeSizeLocale to become like that:
`type ShoeLocale = "EU/IT" | "US/CA" | "AU"`

I tried to do like that

```
type CountryCodes = typeof countrySize;
type CountryCodesKeys = keyof CountryCodes;
type ShoeLocale = CountryCodes[CountryCodesKeys]["name"];
```

but it's not working. The type in this case is `string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just add `as const` assertion to let the ts know that the object won't change:

```
const countrySize = {
  af: {
    name: 'Afghanistan',
    shoeSizeLocale: 'EU/IT',
  },
  al: {
    name: 'Albania',
    shoeSizeLocale: 'AU',
  },
  dz: {
    name: 'Algeria',
    shoeSizeLocale: 'EU/IT',
  },
  ar: {
    name: 'Argentina',
    shoeSizeLocale: 'US/CA',
  },
} as const;
```

Then your types will be as expected. And to add.`type ShoeSizeLocale = "EU/IT" | "US/CA" | "AU"` you can just do the following:

```
type ShoeSizeLocal = CountryCodes[CountryCodesKeys]['shoeSizeLocale'];
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp04Mm)

Comment: what about this case?
`const braSize = {
  IT: {
    "0": ["AA", "A", "B"],
    "1": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
    "2": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
    "5": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
  },
  US: {
    "2": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
    "3": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
    "4": ["AA", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"],
  }
}`

Comment: Can you check [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mL8Gem)? I'm not sure if I understood you

Comment: @Dmytro check [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIYGUCWAvApjAvDAbwFgAoGGASQBUAuQ088gIgAYm6BtJgQW6YBoYPAUIBCTALr8GjJgEZ2MLrxHDBTceoDCqgCKqAoqoBiqgOKqAEqoqqAUqoDSk6WVkAmRcr7qfY1Trq+upG6qbqFurW6rbqDurOUjLMAKxePH5q-tp6hibmVjb2LjIAvq7kAKoodMRuzJ6cGaqZmkKBQsFCoULhQpFC0UKxQvFCiRWyAMzpKr6qbUwdTF1MPUx9TANMQ0wjTGNME8lCACyzma0BuSH5EYUxxUlu5aSlMEgQMKCQUADcpFIUAAngAHHCiFB4GAg8EgABm8GQ6GwAJIQLBOC0AAs0AAbAAmCCwYAAPFQAHzQqgcADWWGBCJgVAkgJIsJwAA1oTj8USSaTeYTiWTIRSKRwwABXAC2cCwCFZJAA9MrGAA9AD8QA) as well

Comment: yep, you helped a lot! thnks