# Define nested properties of object with TS

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

I've already posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76099089/define-nested-properties-via-ts), but have another approach right now. This time I want to define type `BraSize` in this object:

```
const braSizeObj = {
  IT: {
    '0': ['AA', 'A', 'B'],
    '1': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
    '2': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
    '5': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
  },
  US: {
    '2': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
    '3': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
    '4': ['AA', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
  },
} as const;

type BraSize = typeof braSizeObj;
type BraLocale = keyof BraSize; // "IT" | "US"

// type BraSize =           // "0" |  "1" | "2" |  "5" | "3" | "4" 

type BraCup = {
  [K in keyof BraSize]: {
    [K2 in keyof BraSize[K]]: BraSize[K][K2][keyof BraSize[K][K2] & number];
  }[keyof BraSize[K]];
}[keyof BraSize];  // "AA" | "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K"


const braCup: BraCup ='A'
```

Want to implement like this
`const braSize = braSizeObj[braLocale]["0"]`, where variable `braLocale` has `type BraLocale`
In that case i also catch an error because only "0" have first nested object, they both have only "2" key.

here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIYGUCWAvApgeTgKxgF4YBvAKBhgEkAVALjMqpgHIAGVxgbVYEE%20rADRtBI1gCFWAXSHMqrAIxcYvAcNEbJWgMJaAIloCiWgGJaA4loASW6loBSWgNIy5LNgCYVasZvFS4nrihuIm4ubiVuK24vbiTuKusvJsAKw%20-H78WoFswWyhbOFskWzRbLFs8WxOKVQAvu4wAKoojBQerN48WVrZeawFrEWsJaxlrBWsVaw1rIlsyc0KAMyZ6uIDugbGZpY2do4ubqmsACwb2dtBu2H7UYdxx-UwTeQNMEgQMKCQUABucjkKAATwADlgYBJkOhsMQYGDISAAGbwWGYXAEIFIqEwpAAGRAwCQABsoSQANZYUGo6EY7AAmAAemZMAARHR2TAAD4ctrs4GsxEQvEMikeSVUYXs9jcvkcxTyjmeZUctLK9mrTXnbnA3H0pA6ACu4IRnVUzhgaDAMGptLR%20LhWGkHVS3GcnmttvtdKdmI90ldhudgY9nmk3F9jvFYc90hgADIYGBjQBbOBYBDSIGNKM0v2x5xBoENfMOkOYnPStnsgSaviaiSanSa-Saoya0yaiya6ya6iahya5yC4F-aDoo2mxj4k1mog5IA) of it

And if its helps me above i want to define `BraSize` to be `"0" | "1" | "2" | "5" | "3" | "4"`. How do I do that?

Comment: for example to dynamically use this construction
const braCup = braSizeObj[locale][braSize]
where braSize = type BraSize
where locale = type BraLocale

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i want to define BraSize to be such type as // "0" |  "1" | "2" |  "5" | "3" | "4"

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how does your previous question not tell you how to do that?

Comment: cuz i dont get it how to do)

Comment: *"i want to define BraSize to be such type as // "0" | "1" | "2" | "5" | "3" | "4" "* What would you do with it? As you've said in a now-deleted comment, you couldn't use it on `braSizeObj[braLocale][___]`, since it's not a valid key for both `braSizeObj.IT` and `braSizeObj.US`. You could write a generic function to do that operation, is that what you want?

Comment: yes, can u help with it?. I deleted comment and put in the body of my question

Comment: or make some typeGuard funtion

Answer (score 1):

Although you *could* do this ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIYGUCWAvApgeTgKxgF4YBvAKBipgEkAVALjMutYCIAGNpgbTYEF+bADQwBIsQCE2AXWEtWVNgEZuMPoInjRbaToDCWgCJaAoloBiWgOJaAElppaAUloDSs+YupsATGo0hHSCpLUMdEx1zHSsdWx0HHScdVx0POQVFNgBWAIEQ7VCDYzNLG3tHF09MgF8vagBVFCYKbyV-XnytAr0xcLFIsWixWLF4sUSxZLFUsXT67zYAZjzNYK1etn62QbZhtlG2cbZJtmm2WbZ5zPYAFlWCnrCSqLK4iqSqjNY68hqYJAQGCgSBQADc5HIUAAngAHLAwfgAGyRKAArnA3FhoRAADx0AB8xGYrB4WOhMDQYBgAGtsSAAGYwOgyJh06GM5lk7EyCE1HjszksiFQuEIyTIdDYYnI1EY8l4mHwzmIVCYXAEAkQgD02uoAD0APyQoA)), it isn't really useful:

```typescript
type AllSubKeys<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: keyof T[Key];
}[keyof T];

type BraSize = AllSubKeys<typeof braSizeObj>;
//   ^? type BraSize = "0" | "1" | "2" | "5" | "3" | "4";
```

It's not useful because that `BraSize` type isn't a valid key type for either `braSizeObj.IT` or `braSizeObj.US`, since it's a superset of their valid keys.

In a deleted comment you talked about doing `braSizeObj[locale]["0"]`, which suggests to me you want a typesafe way to get entries from your subkey objects. You could do that with a generic function ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIYGUCWAvApgeTgKxgF4YBvAKBipgEkAVALjMutYCIAGNpgbTYEF%20bADQwBIsQCE2AXWEtWVNgEZuMPoInjRbaToDCWgCJaAoloBiWgOJaAElppaAUloDSs%20YupsATGo0hHSCpLUMdEx1zHSsdWx0HHScdVx0POQVFNgBWAIEQ7VCDYzNLG3tHF09MgF8vagBVFCYKbyV-XnytAr0xcLFIsWixWLF4sUSxZLFUsXT67zYAZjzNYK1etn62QbZhtlG2cbZJtmm2WbZ5zPYAFlWCnrCSqLK4iqSqjNY68hqYJAQGCgSBQADc5HIADMAK5gYBQNDgGAAcywUHQ2AAPJkADIgYBIAA2WBgWAAHlAsGAACZAgDWWAAniAoTAoEyAA5YVnwZCY3AEBa0WkUsmU6l0mCMllsjnc3mIVCYQX4Hj4wkkmTkAB8AAoiQTiVgmBrjaI0KLyUwaFaAJTMVgIdEwhBgPnK7B4NWGzVYGQ8S00ikyCE1SEgiAgEkAOkNKL1aIxKr1ZzoWlUdrtYJgAHpczAAOogBD0iDkSPRrBxkAJpMC1P0LT3LM5-MwUwIBAlgFA4MQNDOmmiKAACywzpgaCBYBAYnuU-dSoF3pj9Ar4CjsfjifRDbYTWbbFbeYLxdL5aAA)):

```typescript
function getSize<
    Locale extends keyof typeof braSizeObj,
    Index extends keyof typeof braSizeObj[Locale]
>(locale: Locale, index: Index) {
    return braSizeObj[locale][index];
}

// Usage
console.log(getSize("IT", "1")); // Works
console.log(getSize("IT", "4")); // Error as desired, there is no "4" in braSizeObj.IT
console.log(getSize("US", "4")); // Works
```

...but beware that you couldn't just use strings as second to that, the arguments would have be known to be specifically `"IT"` or `"US"` at compile-time, and similarly if `locale` is known to be `"IT"` then `index` has to be known (at compile-time) to be `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"5"` (or if locale`is`"US"`, then` "2"`,` "3"`, or` "4"`), as above.

In a comment you mentioned type guard functions (aka type predicates). You could certainly define those ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIYGUCWAvApgeTgKxgF4YBvAKBipgEkAVALjMutYCIAGNpgbTYEF+bADQwBIsQCE2AXWEtWVNgEZuMPoInjRbaToDCWgCJaAoloBiWgOJaAElppaAUloDSs+YupsATGo0hHSCpLUMdEx1zHSsdWx0HHScdVx0POQVFNgBWAIEQ7VCDYzNLG3tHF09MgF8vagBVFCYKbyV-XnytAr0xcLFIsWixWLF4sUSxZLFUsXT67zYAZjzNYK1etn62QbZhtlG2cbZJtmm2WbZ5zPYAFlWCnrCSqLK4iqSqjNY68hqYJAQGCgSBQADc5HIUAAngAHLAwSTIdDYPCEEgw+EgABm8GRmFwBAhmIRSNQBIAMiBgEgADYIkgAayw0JxiPxqKJkOxAFcwMAoGhwDA0BAyVSafSABS06l0rBMaAINBgADmAEomLLJQjRTBmazcWSUYTCK1qAgsFAeQgwDBtfKRXbEOTOfgITVuXyBUK7aKyTQwAATLAADwAPBLHWGoFhg0CDWzjQS0TAAGQwJUq1UAPilmQd9KYUfpCydIdDiqgyrV5E15bDIoTLKTHNNPBLWBk6cz1ezzFYluttoboadeNd7cLXY9Xv5guFqqtJplcqLvZrqtEKorVc36oH1DQuKl-uQndXOvVB-N3mPMFPYuQgYrl-l2+DYevh7aFqtNudNs0R4acZB4HcwxkCFf09H5MiHACYDAHlaVpWcgA)):

```typescript
type BraSizeObj = typeof braSizeObj;
type BraSizeLocale = keyof BraSizeObj;

function isBraLocale(locale: string): locale is keyof BraSizeObj {
    return locale in braSizeObj;
}

function isBraIndex<Locale extends keyof BraSizeObj & string>(
    locale: Locale,
    index: string
): index is keyof BraSizeObj[Locale] & string {
    return index in braSizeObj[locale];
}
```

(It's not clear to me why we need the `& string` on the second of those but not the first.)

Then either use them in a `getBraSize` that accepts strings (shown in the playground above):

```typescript
function getSize(locale: string, index: string) {
    if (isBraLocale(locale)) {
        if (isBraIndex(locale, index)) {
            return braSizeObj[locale][index];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

...or use them prior to the `getBraSize` that expects specifically-typed arguments.

Comment: And if i want to check if this pair of Locale and Index is correct as typeGuard function?
for ex.
if(getSize("IT", "1")){
    //works
} else {
//incorrect pair
}

Comment: @Dmytro - The `getBraSize` from the final link above would work like that. (I hadn't actually quoted the code of that function, though it was in the playground. I've fixed that now.)

Comment: You are my hero! God bless u!